# Date Parsing In Apex

Tags: apex, date

I am having birthdate like this as string 'November 1, 2012' and I want to find the age pertaining to current date.

I am trying to convert first into date as like below

```
Date.parse('November 1, 2012')

or

Date.Valueof('November 1, 2012')

or

String strDob='November 1, 2012';
DateTime dtDOB = (DateTime)JSON.deserialize('"' + strDob + '"', DateTime.class);
```

I am always getting invalid date while conversion

Is there any direct approach or do I have to manipulate the above string through string.replace with '/' methods and reverse and then convert to (2012/11/1) and finally parse

```
Date.Parse('2012/11/1')
```

Comment: As per the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_date.htm#apex_System_Date_parse), parsing requires the date format to be one appropriate to the contextual user's locale.

Comment: The title does not seem to have anything to do with the body of this post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this :

```
String strBirthDate = 'November 1, 2012';
String strMonth = strBirthDate.substringbefore(',').substringbefore(' ');
Integer day = integer.valueof(strBirthDate.substringbefore(',').substringafter(' '));
Integer year = integer.valueof(strBirthDate.substringafter(',').substringafter(' '));
Integer month;
switch on strMonth {
   when 'January' {
       month = 1;
   }
   when 'February' {
       month = 2;
   }
   when 'March' {
       month = 3;
   }
   when 'April' {
       month = 4;
   }
    when 'May' {
       month = 5;
   }
    when 'June' {
       month = 6;
   }
    when 'July' {
       month = 7;
   }
    when 'August' {
       month = 8;
   }
    when 'September' {
       month = 9;
   }
    when 'October' {
       month = 10;
   }
    when 'November' {
       month = 11;
   }
    when 'December' {
       month = 12;
   }
}
Date birthDate = Date.newInstance(year,month,day);
Integer age = birthDate.monthsBetween(Date.Today())/12;
```